# AngularJS, Databind Multiple Form Fields

Tags: php, javascript, json, forms, angularjs

Ok i have a Edit Form in AngularJS and i want show data in textboxes through angular databindings.

Here is the Form which i have done so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/styles/formcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="controller">
    <form>
    <label for="name">UserID:</label>   <input type="text" name="UserID" ng-model="user.UserID" value=""><br>
    <label for="UserName">Name:</label>   <input type="text"  name="UserName" ng-model="user.UserName" value=""><br>
    <label for="rollno">In Game Name:</label>   <input type="text" name="GameName" ng-model="user.InGameName" value="" ><br>
    <label for="father">CNIC Number:</label>   <input type="number" name="Cnic" ng-model="user.Cnic" value="" ><br>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>  <input name="Age" ng-model="user.Age" type="number" value="" ><br>
    <label for="email1">Email:</label>   <input name="Email" ng-model="user.Email" type="email" value="" ><br>
    <label for="email2">Res enter Email:</label>   <input id="email2" type="email" name="email2" value=""  ><br>
    <label for="pass1">Password:</label>  <input id="pass1" type="password" name="Pass" ng-model="user.Password" value=""><br>
    <label for="pass2">Re enter Password:</label>  <input id="pass2" type="password" name="pass2" value="" ><br>
    <label  style="margin-bottom:-10px; "  for="male">Male</label><input class="gen" ng-model="user.Gender" id="male" type="radio" name="g" value="Male"><br>
    <label  style="margin-bottom:15px;" for="female">Female</label><input class="gen" ng-model="user.Gender" id="female" type="radio" name="g" value="Female"><br>
    <label class="dis"  for="about" >About:</label> <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="about" type="text" value=""></textarea><br>
    <button style="margin-left: 225px;"  ng-click="save()" >Save</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
       function controller ($scope,$http)
       {
           var angularform="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/datacon/angform"
           $scope.save=function()
           {
            $http.post(angularform, $scope.user);
           }
       }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Json Array I am Getting From the Controller
JSON:

```
{"datas":[{"UserID":"168","UserName":"fdaa","Cnic":"23424","Email":"pak@gmail.com","Password":"asdad","Age":"12","Gender":"Male","Picture":null,"InGameName":"fds","ContactID":null,"GroupID":null,"ClanID":null}]}
```

But How to show these values in TextBoxes through Angular Data bindings?

Or if i am Doing Something Wrong Please Redirect me to my mistakes so i could solve my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I am getting you right or not. But I think If you are using `$scope` and `ng-model`, they are doing their job perfectly. You are using absolutely correct.

With the `$http.post()` you can save the data. At the same time data will be present in the text boxes.

What exactly you want to do. Please explain a bit more so that folks can try to explain you more.